# Excel: How to find Nth day of month

Tags: excel

I'd like to add a column that tells me the Nth day in the month.

For example, December 11, 2018 is the 2nd Tuesday in December.

I'm able to find the Day Number in the month, but not able to add a column for "2nd Tuesday" and so on.

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 2):

For any date,

```
=LOOKUP(DAY(B2), {1,8,15,22,29}, {"1st","2nd","3rd","4h","5th"})&TEXT(B2, " dddd")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Columns C:

`=INT((DAY(B2)-1)/7)+1`

Column D:

`=TEXT(WEEKDAY(B2,1),"dddd")`

Column E:

`=IF(C2=1,"1st",IF(C2=2,"2nd",IF(C2=3,"3rd",C2&"th")))& " "&D2`

Mind you, this is quite convoluted, would work much better as a custom function.

Comment: Nice use of the INT function there. Convoluted or not, this is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is on the link below.
https://exceljet.net/formula/get-nth-day-of-week-in-month